# Need to process a dataset via dynamic runtime code in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic-code

I have been working with C# dynamic code for run time processes. My problem is I cannot seem to pass a dataset object to the dynamic code with out getting:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\mgallanx\AppData\Local\Temp\npbylo5z.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Here is the simplest dataset processing string I am using:

```
mycodestring = "using System; 
    using System.Data; 
    namespace DaCodeNS 
     { 
       public static class DaCode 
        { 
          public static DataSet DaMethod( Dataset dsIn) 
          { 
            return dsIn; 
          }
        }
      }"
```

the calling method sets the parameters to add the `System.dll` and `System.Data.dll`, creates an `Object[] mp` to one element of `sIn`.

The call then is:

```
CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource (parameters, mycodestring);
var cls = results.CompiledAssembly.GetType ("DaCodeNS.DaCode");
var method = cls.GetMethod ("DaMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
return (DataSet)  method.Invoke (null, mp);
```

It breaks at the `GetMethod` line.
I can get similar code passing integers around to play, but changing the return and passed to `DataSet` blows up. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely not including all of the references needed to make your dynamic code compile/run. A simple way to find all the needed references would be to create a standa-alone project that just includes the code you're going to compile. Then look at the references you needed to add to the project to get it to compile/run.

Comment: Thank you Paul, I'll let you know the results

Comment: Ok, some refinement to the issue: I've added 
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add ("System.Data.dll");

Comment: And I've tried full qualified paths to the System.Data.dll. I still get the file not found error at first use of any System.Data vernacular.
Looking forward to you recommendations.

Comment: It might be worth looking the fusion log. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx - Go into settings, enable it, then re-test. That should at least confirm or eliminate that as the cause of the problem.